# Error: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set

Tags: rest, apexrest

I am trying use a REST service by sending a GET HttpRequest to a REST @HttpGet method to retrieve some VisualForce pages and attach them as pdfs to a given record id. I have added the URL of my salesforce to the Remote Site Settings in order for this to work. Prior to this weekend this was working fine, however now this is broken. The HttpResponse comes back with an error

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

and visiting the associated url shows a page with the following error:

> Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set.

```
        //recordId and sessionId are passed into the function, (where sessionId is given as = UserInfo.getSessionId)
        String url = 'https://login.salesforce.com' + '/services/apexrest/<My REST Resource>/' + recordId;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
```

I have also tried setting the URL to use

```
String url = 'https://####.salesforce.com' + '/services/apexrest/<My REST Resource>/' + recordId;
```

Where #### is the unique instance part of the URL, which is how the code was priorly, but that just gave me a 404 error instead.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The former method, using login.salesforce.com, definitely shouldn't work. The latter should work if your authorization header is correct. Make sure you're using an appropriate authorisation header.